# Is it possible to hide the navigationbar in storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

In storyboard, we can hide the tabbar simply, check the controller's `Hide Bottom Bar on Push`.

But, can we hide the navigation bar in storyboard? Is it possible to do that?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the view controller and change Top Bar to none in properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the view controller in storyboard and change the 'Top Bar' metric as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible just set the TopBar attribute to none

[image]